# How to click ion tab in protractor for e2e testing

Tags: html, css, protractor, ionic3, karma-jasmine

I want to be able to navigate my ionic app using e2e.
I am doing this using protractor, by binding element by css.
I want to make an ion-tab to make a click.

`element(by.css('.settingTabButton')).click();`

I wanted to add a css attribute to an ion tab' class in the html so that i could grab that element by its css attribute.

```
<ion-tab class="settingTabButton" [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Settings" 
        tabIcon="md-settings">
```

When I run the test it reports "Failed element not visible":

I think it is failing because ion-tab isn't a button so you can't call element.click() in protractor?

**chrome> Developer console >elements section :**

```
<ion-tab class="settingTabButton" role="tabpanel" tabicon="md-settings" tabtitle="Settings" ng-reflect-root="function SettingsPage(navCtrl," ng-reflect-tab-title="Settings" ng-reflect-tab-icon="md-settings" id="tabpanel-t0-2" aria-labelledby="tab-t0-2" aria-hidden="true"><div></div><div class="nav-decor"></div></ion-tab>
```

Is binding to elements using css the best solution for protractor?

> See below pseudo for my implementation

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab class="settingTabButton" [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Settings" 
        tabIcon="md-settings">
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.scss**:

```
.settingTabButton.important {

}
```

in the **tabs.ts** :

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
  styleUrls: ['/tabs.scss']
})
```

**example.e2e-spec.ts**

```
describe('Login', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      page.navigateTo('http://localhost:8100/');
    });

    it('as unregistered user be able to navigate to setting screen', () => {
        element(by.css('.settingTabButton')).click().then(() => { // fails         here 
        expect(true).toBe(true);
      });
    });

 })
```

Comment: I think it is better to use id instead of empty css variables.

Answer (score 2):

My solution in the end was to read the chrome developer console. I noticed that the tabs each had an id associated with them

```
<a ... id="tab-t0-0" ...</a>
```

So I created a tab page object to get each tab button by its id:

```
getHomeTab(){
return element(by.id('tab-t0-0')).getWebElement();
```

}

And then I used that to navigate in each respective page object:

```
export class SettingPagePo {
    navigateTo(){
    var tab = new TabPagePo;
    tab.getSettingsTab().click();
    browser.driver.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

element(by.css('.settingTabButton')).click();

Since settingTabButton is a class name, it requires a dot in front of it. ".settingTabButton"

Comment: Thanks i updated the question. What you said is correct but doesn't answer my question completely

Comment: You can try locating elements with a given tag name http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.tagName   element(by.tagName("ion-tab"))

Answer (score 0):

Before you can click a (tab-)button, you need to guarantee that it is already rendered. I had the same problem and found out that protractor has a library ExpectedConditions, which can help you out: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.

In your case the solution might look like this:

```
import {ExpectedConditions, by, element} from 'protractor';
describe('Login', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      page.navigateTo('http://localhost:8100/');
    });

    it('as unregistered user be able to navigate to setting screen', () => {
        let settingTabButton= await waitForClickability('.settingTabButton');
        await browser.actions()
        .mouseMove(settingTabButton)
        .click()
        .perform();
      });
    });

 })

 async function waitForClickability(selector){
    let el = element(by.css(selector));
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el), 5000);
    return el;
  }
```